# Create Normal Distribution Curve for Data

Tags: normal-distribution, graphing-functions

Following this [tutorial](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html)

I would like to plot normal distribution curve for following data

```
Location (Location)        Avg_Rating
Starbucks                  2.119402985
Shish Boom Bah Car Wash    1.666666667
Pirates of Grill           4.363636364
Mortons                    4.625
Lorianna's Boutique        3.982142857
Harry's Collection         3.835820896
Eat at Joes                3.592592593
Brats and Cuties           4.384615385
Belfrance Chocolate        4.735294118
Barista                    3.553571429
```

Mean = 3.796
St Dev = 1.277

So far, I have accompanying z-value and histogram. But how to make normal distribution curve? What to plot z-value against?

```
Location (Location)             Avg_Rating      Z-score
Starbucks                        2.119402985    -1.312918571
Shish Boom Bah Car Wash          1.666666667    -1.667449752
Pirates of Grill                 4.363636364    0.444507724
Mortons                          4.625000000    0.64917776
Lorianna's Boutique              3.982142857    0.145765745
Harry's Collection               3.835820896    0.031183161
Eat at Joes                      3.592592593    -0.159285362
Brats and Cuties                 4.384615385    0.460936088
Belfrance Chocolate              4.735294118    0.735547469
Barista                          3.553571429    -0.189842264
```

[image]

And this is how z-values look if I plot against location

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You plot number of locations vs ratings to see the normal distribution.

Let the X-axis have ratings chosen at certain resolution, say, 0.5. The Y-axis has number of locations that have the rating fall in the window you have chosen.

eg: between 3.5 and 4 you have 3 locations.

Since the data is too small dont expect to see a perfect bell curve.

Comment: `eg: between 3.5 and 4 you have 3 locations.` how to determine this? Can you provide links? I am trying to research this myself, but having difficulty.

Comment: Sort based on the rating.